# Code-Golf: Lattice Points inside a Circle

Tags: code-golf, geometry, restricted-time

The following picture shows the problem:

[image]

Write a function that, given an integer as the circle radius, calculates the number of lattice points inside the *centered* circle (including the boundary).

The image shows:

```
f[1] = 5  (blue points)
f[2] = 13 (blue + red points)
```

other values for your checking/debugging:

```
f[3]    = 29
f[10]   = 317
f[1000] = 3,141,549
f[2000] = 12,566,345
```

Should have a reasonable performance. Let's say less than a minute for f[1000].

Shortest code wins. Usual Code-Golf rules apply.

Please post the calculation and timing of f[1001] as an example.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A328

Comment: [Triangular version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/163704/triangular-lattice-points-close-to-the-origin).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### J, <strike>21</strike> <strike>19</strike> 18

```
+/@,@(>:|@j./~@i:)
```

Builds complexes from -x-xj to x+xj and takes magnitude.

Edit: With `>:`

Edit 2: With hook and monadic `~`. Runs a few times slower for some reason, but still 10-ish seconds for f(1000).

Comment: Oh hey, I didn't know about `i:`, I am *so* stealing that, thanks!

Comment: @J B: Yeah, well... I'm stealing `>:`. *derp*

Comment: I wish I understood caps well enough to steal those too O:-)

Comment: This answer is depressingly short (to someone who's never bothered to learn a short and/or golfing lang) `>:`. But hey, that's a cool answer! `:)`

Answer (score 5):

### J, <s>27</s> 21

```
3 :'+/,y>:%:+/~*:i:y'
```

Very brutal: computes *sqrt(x²+y²)* over the *[-n,n]* range and counts items *≤n*.  Still very acceptable times for 1000.

**Edit**: `i:y` is quite a bit shorter than `y-i.>:+:y`.  Thanks [Jesse Millikan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1938/code-golf-lattice-points-inside-a-circle/1943#1943)!

Comment: Ha! That was the idea behind asking a decent performance! Just curious: What is the timing for 1000?

Comment: @belisarius: 0.86s.  On 10-year old hardware.  3.26s for 2000.

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby 1.9, <del>62 58</del> 54 characters

```
f=->r{1+4*eval((0..r).map{|i|"%d"%(r*r-i*i)**0.5}*?+)}
```

Example:

```
f[1001]
=> 3147833

t=Time.now;f[1001];Time.now-t
=> 0.003361411
```

Answer (score 4):

**Python 55 Chars**

```
f=lambda n:1+4*sum(int((n*n-i*i)**.5)for i in range(n))
```

Comment: `f=lambda n:1+4*sum(int((n*n-i*i)**.5)for i in range(n))` is 17 characters shorter.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 41 bytes

```haskell
f n=1+4*sum[floor$sqrt$n*n-x*x|x<-[0..n]]
```

Counts points in the quadrant `x>=0, y>0`, multiplies by 4, adds 1 for the center point.

Answer (score 3):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), 13 bytes

```
∧+1×4⌊√×⊃+-⇡.
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4oinKzHDlzTijIriiJot4oipJ8OXLuKHoS4KZiDihpAg4oinKzHDlzTijIriiJrDl-KKgyst4oehLgoKZiAxCmYgMgpmIDMKZiAxMApmIDEwMDAKZiAyMDAw)

Uses the formula on [A057655](https://oeis.org/A057655) \$ 1+4\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n^2-k^2}\right\rfloor} \$, and uses the fact that `k=n` part can be removed.

```
∧+1×4⌊√×⊃+-⇡.    input: integer n
            ⇡.    keep n and generate the range for k
       ×⊃+-      (n+k) * (n-k) for each k
      ⌊√          sqrt, floor
∧+1×4            multiply 4, sum, and add 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 44 bytes

```haskell
f n|w<-[-n..n]=sum[1|x<-w,y<-w,x*x+y*y<=n*n]
```

Comment: I'm new to Haskell: How can you write `w<-[-n..n]` where (usually) there is a boolean value?

Comment: @flawr These are [pattern guards](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pattern_guard), which succeed if a pattern is matched, but can be used in golfing as a shorter let. See [this tip](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76749/20260).

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this this thread!

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-x`, 12 bytes

```
òUn)ï Ëx²§U²
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8lVuKe8gy3iyp1Wy&input=MTAwCi14)

Explanation:

```
òUn)            #Get the range [-input ... input]
    ï           #Get each pair of numbers in that range
      Ë         #For each pair:
       x        # Get the sum...
        ²       # Of the squares
         §      # Check if that sum is less than or equal to...
          U²    # The input squared
                #Output the number of pairs that passed the check
```

Comment: [12 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8lVuKe8gy3iyp1Wy&input=MTAwCi14)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 80 bytes

```
n=>(a=[...Array(n+n+1)].map(_=>i--,i=n)).map(x=>a.map(y=>r+=x*x+y*y<=n*n),r=0)|r
```

Alternative version, also 80 bytes:

```
n=>[...Array(n+n+1)].map((_,x,a)=>a.map((_,y)=>r+=x*x+(y-=n)*y<=n*n,x-=n),r=0)|r
```

ES7 version, also 80 bytes:

```
n=>[...Array(n+n+1)].map((_,x,a)=>a.map((_,y)=>r+=(x-n)**2+(y-n)**2<=n*n),r=0)|r
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 48 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=0:i>n or(n*n-i*i)**.5//1*4+f(n,i+1)
```

Like [fR0DDY's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1940/20260), but recursive, and returns a float. Returning an int is 51 bytes:

```python
f=lambda n,i=0:i>n or 4*int((n*n-i*i)**.5)+f(n,i+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <strike>85</strike> 83 bytes

The code:

```
function f($n){for($x=$n;$x;$c+=$x,$y++)for(;$n*$n<$x*$x+$y*$y;$x--);return$c*4+1;}
```

Its outcome (check https://3v4l.org/bC0cY for multiple PHP versions):

```
f(1001)=3147833
time=0.000236 seconds.
```

The ungolfed code:

```
/**
 * Count all the points having x > 0, y >= 0 (a quarter of the circle)
 * then multiply by 4 and add the origin.
 *
 * Walk the lattice points in zig-zag starting at ($n,0) towards (0,$n), in the
 * neighbourhood of the circle. While outside the circle, go left.
 * Go one line up and repeat until $x == 0.
 * This way it checks about 2*$n points (i.e. its complexity is linear, O(n))
 *
 * @param int $n
 * @return int
 */
function countLatticePoints2($n)
{
    $count = 0;
    // Start on the topmost right point of the circle ($n,0), go towards the topmost point (0,$n)
    // Stop when reach it (but don't count it)
    for ($y = 0, $x = $n; $x > 0; $y ++) {
        // While outside the circle, go left;
        for (; $n * $n < $x * $x + $y * $y; $x --) {
            // Nothing here
        }
        // ($x,$y) is the rightmost lattice point on row $y that is inside the circle
        // There are exactly $x lattice points on the row $y that have x > 0
        $count += $x;
    }
    // Four quarters plus the center
    return 4 * $count + 1;
}
```

A naive implementation that checks `$n*($n+1)` points (and runs 1000 times slower but still computes `f(1001)` in less than 0.5 seconds) and the test suite (using the sample data provided in the question) can be found [on github](https://github.com/axiac/code-golf/blob/master/lattice-points-inside-a-circle.php).

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 14 bytes

```apl
{≢⍸⍵≥|⌾⍀⍨⍵…-⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/6sfdS561LvjUe/WR51Lax717HvU2/CodwWI37BMF0jV/k8DKnzU2wfR09V8aL3xo7aJQF5wkDOQDPHwDP6fpmBoYPAfAA)

Despite lacking the `i:` (inclusive range from -n to n) builtin of J, APL Extended has shorter syntax in other areas.

```apl
{≢⍸⍵≥|⌾⍀⍨⍵…-⍵}            Monadic function taking an argument n.
           ⍵…-⍵             n, n-1, ..., -n
      ⌾⍀                   Make a table of complex numbers
                            (equivalent to ∘.{⍺+1J×⍵} in Dyalog APL)
         ⍨                  with both real and imaginary parts from that list.
      |                       Take their magnitudes.
    ⍵≥                        1 where a magnitude are is at most n, and 0 elsewhere.
 ⍸                           Get all indices of truthy values.
≢                            Find the length of the resulting list.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 60 bytes

```c
r,a;f(x){for(a=r=x*x;a--;)r-=hypot(a%x+1,a/x)>x;x=4*r+1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bci9CoMwEADg3ccQhDtNqLHdjvRJuhwpsYJ/nA5XxFdvunRrvvELtg8hJTFMERSPuAiwF6@1EltLKNa/3uuyA1faOMMXxbuS@lstjaMzTTzMgEdRrDLMe4Syej7m0kRwiPSXXS6vuXRtftvsd78/0yfEkfst2XH6Ag)

Loops over the first quadrant, multiplies the result by 4 and adds one. Slightly less golfed

```c
r,a;
f(x){
  for(a=r=x*x;a--;)
    r-=hypot(a%x+1,a/x)>x;
  x=4*r+1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 55 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY2xCsIwFEV3v@KOScXQglOhBUeHTuIkDs/a1kj6WpNXQaTfHuNyhwP3nNCSozjdnl0raMgyvhvgTQ59iSNLVadBhchVrXIsLNaBtRlpVraqG5KHCS8vijPe2cxqI1N6aBOWMdtviwjcux5jMivyQyhx8J4@l5N4y8NVlzizTYF/FZgTFMeqV0WeF1onuG7W@AM)

```
n=>(0 until n).map(i=>Math.sqrt(n*n-i*i).toInt).sum*4+1
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7), 42 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,k=n)=>k--?((n*n-k*k)**.5<<2)+f(n,k):1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZctLDsIgFIXhuavokIvQ9vKo0RRdS1OLsTRgrHH7WByQiGf6/Wce3sM6Pu@PF/fhOsVoDfHMGQ/m7Di/EOKp5446oLTWfS9gb1MAJ4xj8GtYpnoJN2IJAlTbmqbSu18RWVAWJDOJY0HYfm0jiYc/a5MmY6iQaVW@RS5QMN11TCodPw)

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure/ClojureScript, 85 chars

```
#(apply + 1(for[m[(inc %)]x(range 1 m)y(range m):when(<=(+(* x x)(* y y))(* % %))]4))
```

Brute forces the first quadrant, including the y axis but not the x axis.  Generates a 4 for every point, then adds them together with 1 for the origin.  Runs in under 2 seconds for input of 1000.

Abuses the hell out of `for` to define a variable and save a few characters.  Doing the same to create an alias for `range` doesn't save any characters (and makes it run significantly slower), and it seems unlikely that you're going to save anything by making a square function.

Comment: This is quite an old question, are you sure this answer would have worked at the time?

Comment: @muddyfish I didn't notice the age, just saw it near the top.  Clojure predates the question, but I don't know its history enough to know about language changes.

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 14 bytes

```
QFXQX-_,B)s}}h
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=QFXQX-_%2CB%29s%7D%7Dh&input=1)

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 35 characters

```
f[n_]:=Sum[SquaresR[2,k],{k,0,n^2}]
```

Lifted from https://oeis.org/A000328

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SquaresR.html

`SquaresR[2,k]` is the number of ways to represent k as the sum of two squares, which is the same as the number of lattice points on a circle of radius k^2. Sum from k=0 to k=n^2 to find all the points on or inside a circle of radius n.

Comment: `2~SquaresR~k~Sum~{k,0,#^2}&` to make it shorter

Answer (score 0):

## Tcl, 111 bytes

```
lassign {1001 0 -1} r R x
while {[incr x]<$r} {set R [expr {$R+floor(sqrt($r*$r-$x*$x))}]}
puts [expr {4*$R+1}]
```

Simple discrete **x** loop over quadrant I, counting largest **y** using the Pythagorean Theorem at each step. Result is 4 times the sum plus one (for the center point).

The size of the program depends on the value of **r**. Replace `{1001 0 -1}` with `"$argv 0 -1"` and you can run it with any command-line argument value for **r**.

Computes f(1001) → `3147833.0` in about 1030 microseconds, AMD Sempron 130 2.6GHz 64-bit processor, Windows 7.

<sub>Obviously, the larger the radius, the closer the approximation to PI: f(10000001) runs in about 30 seconds producing a 15-digit value, which is about the precision of a IEEE double.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ä÷²M╨⌐■╝^₧░
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=84f6fd4dd0a9febc5e9eb0&i=1%0A2%0A3%0A10%0A1000%0A2000&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 128 B

This just walks the lattice grid and checks whether the distance to the origin is less than or equal to the radius.

```pascal
type Z=integer;function f(r:Z):Z;var x,y,n:Z;begin
n:=0;for x:=-r to r do for y:=-r to r do n:=n+ord(sqrt(x*x+y*y)<=r);f:=n
end;
```

User time on a *busy* Linux x86‑64 machine for calculating `f(1001) = 3147833`: ca. 80 ms.
Calculate just the points in one quadrant to cut the time.

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc), 116 bytes

```
a,x,y;c(r){for(x=-r;x<=r;x++)for(y=-r;y<=r;a+=x*x+y*y<=r*r,y++);return a;}main(r){scanf("%u",&r);printf("%d",c(r));}
```

**How it works**

This inefficient method draws a square around the circle then iterates through all lattice points \$(x,y)\$ within it and checking if \$x^2+y^2 \le r^2 \$.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY3bCsIwEER/RQJKrtA@r/mYZTWloFG2LSZIf921@zJwDsMMpYlIBGOLHciy@5YX25YTQ7vmI0JwarqargZDbr6F7pU8x340gO/rxvWEsD9xrjqzENZizXkz8cIO3jzXVflmot442EXGYRh/VB44LZI@fw)

Comment: Hello, I'd like to shorten my answer above by using this tio.run technique from this [C example](https://tio.run/##bci9CoMwEADg3ccQhDtNqLHdjvRJuhwpsYJ/nA5XxFdvunRrvvELtg8hJTFMERSPuAiwF6@1EltLKNa/3uuyA1faOMMXxbuS@lstjaMzTTzMgEdRrDLMe4Syej7m0kRwiPSXXS6vuXRtftvsd78/0yfEkfst2XH6Ag). Any tips to make it work so it results in fewer bytes? Thanks.

Comment: [111 bytes](https://tio.run/##Jc1NCsIwEEDhq0hAyV@hXU9zmGE0paBRpi3NIPXojgSX3@Y96iYiVYw1CpBl985PtjV9GGoII4Nrlmb5G0OqvgbxMib2DHxbNy4nhOOBc2mFhbBka86biRd28OK5rM1XE9vBwaE69P3wpXzHadFu/wE "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ceilngcat Is there a way to make it even shorter? I've asked the question [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26232/using-tio-run-how-does-a-function-return-a-value). Thanks.

Comment: [73 bytes](https://tio.run/##dc1NCsIwEIbhvacoBSF/hVSX09zEzTCaUtAoY8WEUo9upOjOZvk@w8dQ0xPljCaaBCRYTugs@CuL6F4MUeuOQS6dlk7fRu2iijqp1DlWDHwaHxwqhDlfcAhCTpvqxkMYvai3x0OoDYlWSvjX3aruV7W1BbbFQ@HpbzHnN/kz9vfcPD8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks for those saved bytes and the TIO example. Is there a way to remove that `return` statement? I think there's a way to resolve that using a code golf that returns the value such as `x=a`.

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)), 28 bytes

```
{1+4×⍵++/,(×⍨⍵)≥+/¨×⍨∘.,⍨⍳⍵}
{                          } dfn
                     ∘.,⍨⍳⍵  get cartesian square of 1..n
                   ×⍨        square each half of each pair
                +/¨          add each half of each pair
       +/,     ≥             count sums greater than
          (×⍨⍵)                  the input squared
 1+4×⍵+                      add the input, multiply by 4, and add 1
```

Finds the lattice points in one quadrant, then multiplies it by 4 and adds the points on the axes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v9pQ2@Tw9Ee9W7W19XU0QKwVQI7mo86l2vqHVkD4HTP0dMDim4FStf/dHrVNIF0b16O@qUCNbgqGcJYRnGWMkDUwMPgPAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
(Ÿn¬sãO@O
```

Port of [*@KamilDrakari*'s Japt answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179659/52210), so make sure to upvote that answer as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f4@iOvENrig8v9nfw///f0MDAEAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXLf42jO/IOrSk@vNjfwf@/zv9oQx0jHWMdQwMgAmMwARQEsmIB). (Runs `1001` in about 3.5 seconds on TIO.)

**Explanation:**

```python
(          # Negate the (implicit) input-integer
 Ÿ         # Push a list in the range [(implicit) input,-input]
  n        # Square each inner value
   ¬       # Push the first item (without popping the list), which is input²
    s      # Swap so the list is at the top again
     ã     # Cartesian power of 2 to get all possible pairs
      O    # Sum all those inner pairs together
       @   # Check for each whether the input² is >= this value
        O  # Sum to get the amount of truthy values
           # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

[Try it online with a step-by-step output.](https://tio.run/##VZAxSwQxEIV7f8Ww1R6soK1wKliIjSdYisXcObsJ7ia5ZOLi77G1ukKsV/xdazI5PSzCQN5737zEBlxrmufqxrjIZ1A1y@nj4qi6pQ6ZgBWB/lXqIt1ZB2iewMWgAKHXgZNHrB5NR/AgieZYxmNOfn@W6P02oicg3Ch4wT5SFk3RromF0WqfgUwD1EKYdgsYNSsbGZx1TptOjHlxzk/ve/iIrpFmXUJh3yd3CHrdEzhMULDtv1z4etsH41AqaWPIiznrq6JeKdo8Q2t98YyKEsQffmbagQ5wvkw3af696vLAZiuNcgIHGw1LEx9ZvRZ/gHpUOhdIJaNPhxN4ISWaeT49@QE)

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 25 chars

```
{1+4×+/⌊√(⍵*2)-¨2*⍨¯1+⍳⍵}
```

test:

```
  f←{1+4×+/⌊√(⍵*2)-¨2*⍨¯1+⍳⍵}
  f 0
1
  f 1
5
  f 3
29
  f 10
317
  f 1000
3141549
  f 2000
12566345
```