# Tips for golfing in Haskell

Tags: code-golf, tips, haskell

What general tips do you have for golfing in Haskell? I am looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to Haskell. Please post only one tip per answer.

---

If you are new to golfing in Haskell, please have a look at the **[Guide to Golfing Rules in Haskell](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11935/56433)**. There is also a dedicated Haskell chat room: [Of Monads and Men](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66515/of-monads-and-men).

Comment: Seeing the number of answers till now, I am in doubt about whether Haskell is even a good language for code golfing or not?

Comment: Why only one tip per answer? Also, every language is a good language for golfing. Just don't always expect to win.

Comment: @unclemeat This way people could upvote the good ones to the top without upvoting the bad ones only because they were written by the same guy in the same answer.

Comment: Special request, String compression.

Comment: This is probably not suited as an anwer, but I'm still want to add it here: https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers_miscellaneous#One-liners

Comment: Another (rather funny, but still interesting) one: http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html

Comment: Also another link: https://wiki.haskell.org/Blow_your_mind

Answer (score 51):

## Define infix operators instead of binary functions

This saves usually one or two spaces per definition or call.

```
0!(y:_)=y
x!(y:z)=(x-1)!z
```

vs.

```
f 0(y:_)=y
f x(y:z)=f(x-1)z
```

---

The available symbols for 1-byte operators are `!`, `#`, `%`, `&`, and `?`. All other ASCII punctuation is either already defined as an operator by the Prelude (such as `$`) or has a special meaning in Haskell's syntax (such as `@`).

If you need more than five operators, you could use combinations of the above, such as `!#`, or certain Unicode punctuation characters, such as these (all 2 bytes in UTF-8):

```
¡ ¢ £ ¤ ¥ ¦ § ¨ © ¬ ® ¯ ° ± ´ ¶ · ¸ ¿ × ÷
```

Comment: Note: this can also be used for functions with three or more arguments. `(x!y)z=x+y*z` and `(x#y)z u=x*z+y*u` both work as expected.

Comment: This can also be used for function arguments, e.g. `\f g(!)x y->f g!x y` instead of `\f g j x y->j(f g)(x y)`

Comment: Sometimes it's beneficial to change unary functions to binary operators if you'd otherwise have to use parentheses - `g x=…;g(f x)` is longer than `_?x=…;0!f x`

Answer (score 34):

Use pointless (or -free) notation where appropriate

Often a function with one or two parameters can be written point free.

So a lookup for a list of tuples whose elements are swapped is naïvely written as:

```
revlookup :: Eq b => b -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe a
revlookup e l=lookup e(map swap l)
```

(the type is there just to help you understand what it's doing.)

for our purposes this is much better:

```
revlookup=(.map swap).lookup
```

Answer (score 34):

Use guards not conditionals:

```hs
f a=if a>0 then 3 else 7
g a|a>0=3|True=7
```

Use semicolons not indents

```hs
f a=do
  this
  that
g a=do this;that
```

Use boolean expressions for boolean functions

```hs
f a=if zzz then True else f yyy
g a=zzz||f yyy
```

(SO is being a pain about letting me post these separately)

Comment: also, use multiple guards instead of `&&` when inside a list comprehension.

Comment: Good one Jan - you should make that into an answer, I'll vote for it

Comment: The first example can be further shortened by `True` => `1>0`

Comment: in the first example, I assume you mean `f a=if a>0 then 3 else 7`

Comment: Guard even works if there's no argument in it.

Comment: 6<9 > 1>0 change my mind

Answer (score 32):

## Use the list monad

A quick review:

```
xs >> ys        =  concat $ replicate (length xs) ys
xs >>= f        =  concatMap f xs
mapM id[a,b,c]  =  cartesian product of lists: a × b × c
mapM f[a,b,c]   =  cartesian product of lists: f a × f b × f c
```

Examples:

- #### Repeating a list twice

  ```
  Prelude> "aa">>[1..5]
  [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
  ```
- #### Shorter `concatMap`

  ```
  Prelude> reverse=<<["Abc","Defgh","Ijkl"]
  "cbAhgfeDlkjI"
  ```
- #### Shorter `concat` + list comprehension

  ```
  Prelude> do x<-[1..5];[1..x]
  [1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5]
  ```
- #### Cartesian product

  ```
  Prelude> mapM id["Hh","io",".!"]
  ["Hi.","Hi!","Ho.","Ho!","hi.","hi!","ho.","ho!"]
  ```
- #### List of coordinates on a lattice

  ```
  Prelude> mapM(\x->[0..x])[3,2]
  [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2],[3,0],[3,1],[3,2]]
  ```

Comment: Annother use I found useful is `[0..b]>>[a]` instead of `replicate a b`.

Comment: @WheatWizard `a<$[1..b]` is even shorter, for `replicate`.

Comment: Using `=<<` forces you to import `Control.Monad`. If you don't need that for some other reason, swapping the arguments and using `>>=` seems more concise.

Comment: OTOH, if you need `Data.Traversable` anyway, the Cartesian product example can be shortened to `for["Hh","io",".!"]id`.

Comment: [`(=<<)` is in Prelude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-61--60--60-), actually! I've used it a lot.

Comment: An alternative to `mapM id` for the cartesian product is `sequence :: (Monad m, Traversable t) => t (m a) -> m (t a)` but it is one byte longer, but can be handy if you have to pass it to some other function.

Answer (score 27):

## Use GHC 7.10

*The first version of GHC that contained this stuff was released on **March 27, 2015**.*

It's the latest version, and Prelude got some new additions that are useful for golfing:

### The `(<$>)` and `(<*>)` operators

These useful operators from `Data.Applicative` made it in! **`<$>` is just `fmap`, so you can replace `map f x` and `fmap f x` with `f<$>x` everywhere and win back bytes.** Also, `<*>` is useful in the `Applicative` instance for lists:

```hs
Prelude> (,)<$>[1..2]<*>"abcd"
[(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(1,'c'),(1,'d'),(2,'a'),(2,'b'),(2,'c'),(2,'d')]
```

### The `(<$)` operator

`x<$a` is equivalent to `fmap (const x) a`; i.e. replace every element in a container by `x`.

This is often a nice alternative to `replicate`: `4<$[1..n]` is shorter than `replicate n 4`.

### The Foldable/Traversable Proposal

The following functions got lifted from working on lists `[a]` to general `Foldable` types `t a`:

```hs
fold*, null, length, elem, maximum, minimum, sum, product
and, or, any, all, concat, concatMap
```

This means they now also work on `Maybe a`, where they behave just like "lists with at most one element". For example, `null Nothing == True`, or `sum (Just 3) == 3`. Similarly, `length` returns 0 for `Nothing` and 1 for `Just` values. Instead of writing `x==Just y` you can write `elem y x`.

You can also apply them on tuples, which works as if you'd called `\(a, b) -> [b]` first. It's almost completely useless, but `or :: (a, Bool) -> Bool` is one character shorter than `snd`, and `elem b` is shorter than `(==b).snd`.

### The Monoid functions `mempty` and `mappend`

Not often a life-saver, but if you can infer the type, `mempty` is one byte shorter than `Nothing`, so there's that.

Comment: +1 It's great to hear about '<$>` and `<*>` making it into Prelude! That should be usefull even when It's not code golf (applicative is such a long word).

Comment: Warning about flat replacement: if your language version is newer than the challenge, your solution is inegligible for winning. If you want to update your existing answers or answer, don't overwrite your existing solution. Write an appendix.

Comment: Funny there is `[1..2]` in there. that's just `[1,2]`

Comment: In the same version we also got `<*` from `Applicative`, which for lists is `xs <* ys == concatMap (replicate (length ys)) xs`. This is different from `xs >> ys` or `xs *> ys` which is `concat (replicate (length ys)) xs`. `pure` which is a shorter `return` came at this point too.

Comment: You can now use `<>` instead of `mappend`, it's now (with GHC 8.4.1) part of the `Prelude`.

Comment: @BMO I used `<>` to successfully beat the old quine (with the function instance, which H.PWiz then improved with the `IO` instance), so it is definitely worth mentioning.

Comment: Occasionally you can use `fail""` instead of `Nothing`.

Comment: Now I know why FTP was finally accepted.

Answer (score 26):

Use `1<2` instead of `True` and `1>2` instead of `False`.

```
g x|x<10=10|True=x
f x|x<10=10|1<2=x
```

Comment: This isn't really specific to Haskell: it's applicable to just about every language which has a Boolean type as opposed to truthy and falsy values of other types.

Comment: Can anyone explain this?

Comment: this isn't a good example, i would just golf this as `f=max 10`.

Comment: @MasterMastic this is just writing `if(true)` in other languages. in the prelude, otherwise is actually the boolean value `True`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think this is still valuable for new haskellians (like me) as I first learned to use `otherwise`.

Answer (score 25):

## `interact :: (String → String) → IO ()`

People often forget that this function exists - it grabs all of stdin and applies it to a (pure) function. I often see `main`-code along the lines of

```hs
main=getContents>>=print.foo
```

while

```hs
main=interact$show.foo
```

is quite a bit shorter. It is in the Prelude so no need for imports!

Answer (score 25):

## Use list comprehensions (in clever ways)

Everyone knows they're useful syntax, often shorter than `map` + a lambda:

```
Prelude> [[1..x]>>show x|x<-[1..9]]
["1","22","333","4444","55555","666666","7777777","88888888","999999999"]
```

Or `filter` (and optionally a `map` at the same time):

```
Prelude> [show x|x<-[1..60],mod 60x<1]
["1","2","3","4","5","6","10","12","15","20","30","60"]
```

But there are some weirder uses that come in handy now and then. For one, a list comprehension doesn't need to contain any `<-` arrows at all:

```
Prelude> [1|False]
[]
Prelude> [1|True]
[1]
```

Which means instead of `if p then[x]else[]`, you can write `[x|p]`. Also, to count the number of elements of a list satisfying a condition, intuitively you would write:

```
length$filter p x
```

But this is shorter:

```
sum[1|y<-x,p y]
```

Comment: I actually used all of these before, but I didn't think to put them here.

Answer (score 22):

### Match a constant value

A list comprehension can pattern match on a constant.

---

```haskell
[0|0<-l]
```

This extracts the 0's of a list `l`, i.e. makes a list of as many 0's as are in `l`.

---

```haskell
[1|[]<-f<$>l]
```

This makes a list of as many `1`'s as there are elements of `l` that `f` takes to the empty list (using `<$>` as infix `map`). Apply `sum` to count these elements.

Compare:

```haskell
[1|[]<-f<$>l]
[1|x<-l,f x==[]]
```

---

```haskell
[x|(0,x)<-l]
```

A constant can be used as part of a pattern match. This extracts the second entries of all tuples whose first entry is `0`.

---

Note that all of these require an actual constant literal, not a the value of a variable. For example, `let x=1 in [1|x<-[1,2,3]]` will output `[1,1,1]`, not `[1]`, because the outer `x` binding is overwritten.

Answer (score 21):

## Know your `Prelude`

Fire up GHCi and scroll through the [Prelude documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html). Whenever you cross a function that has a short name, it can pay off to look for some cases where it might be useful.

For example, suppose you wish to transform a string `s = "abc\ndef\nghi"` into one that's space-separated, `"abc def ghi"`. The obvious way is:

```
unwords$lines s
```

But you can do better if you abuse `max`, and the fact that `\n < space < printable ASCII`:

```
max ' '<$>s
```

Another example is [`lex :: String -> [(String, String)]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lex), which does something quite mysterious:

```
Prelude> lex "   some string of Haskell tokens  123  "
[("some"," string of Haskell tokens  123  ")]
```

Try `fst=<<lex s` to get the first token from a string, skipping whitespace. [Here](http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?Divide+section/henkma_1292522156&hs) is a clever solution by henkma that uses `lex.show` on `Rational` values.

Comment: `lookup` is another useful prelude function

Answer (score 19):

## Arguments can be shorter than definitions

I just got outgolfed in a very curious way by [henkma](http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?String+in+String+in+String/henkma_1487067285&hs).

If an auxiliary function `f` in your answer uses an operator that isn’t used elsewhere in your answer, and `f` is called once, make the operator an argument of `f`.

This:

```
(!)=take
f a=5!a++3!a
reverse.f
```

Is two bytes longer than this:

```
f(!)a=5!a++3!a
reverse.f take
```

Answer (score 17):

Use `words` instead of a long list of strings. This isn't really specific to Haskell, other languages have similar tricks too.

```hs
["foo","bar"]
words"foo bar"  -- 1 byte longer
```

```hs
["foo","bar","baz"]
words"foo bar baz"  -- 1 byte shorter
```

```hs
["foo","bar","baz","qux"]
words"foo bar baz qux"    -- 3 bytes shorter
```

Answer (score 17):

### Shorter conditional

```haskell
last$x:[y|b]
```

is equivalent to

```haskell
if b then y else x
```

Here's how it works:

```haskell
             [y|b]   x:[y|b]   last$x:[y|b]
if...      +--------------------------------
b == False | []      [x]       x
b == True  | [y]     [x,y]     y
```

Comment: Wouldnt using `bool` be shorter as you don't need a list  comprehension

Comment: @Potato44 That's in Data.Bool, which costs bytes to import.

Answer (score 16):

## Know your monadic functions

1)
simulate monadic functions using `mapM`.

a lot of times code will have `sequence(map f xs)`, but it can be replaced with `mapM f xs`. even when just using `sequence` alone it is longer then `mapM id`.

2)
combine functions using `(>>=)` (or `(=<<)`)

the function monad version of `(>>=)` is defined as so:

```
(f >>= g) x = g (f x) x
```

it can be useful for creating functions which can't be expressed as a pipeline. for example, `\x->x==nub x` is longer than `nub>>=(==)`, and `\t->zip(tail t)t` is longer than `tail>>=zip`.

Comment: +1 -- I hadn't even realised that there was a monad instance for functions.  that could be very handy :)

Comment: Side note: Though it's part of `Applicative` and not `Monad` there's the implementation for `pure` as well which is shorter than `const` and actually helped me before.

Answer (score 16):

## Shorter conditionals when one outcome is the empty list

When you need a conditional which returns the list `A` or the empty list `[]` depending on some condition `C`, then there exist some shorter alternatives to the usual conditional constructs:

```hs
if(C)then(A)else[] -- the normal conditional
last$[]:[A|C]      -- the golfy all-round-conditional
concat[A|C]        -- shorter and works when surrounded by infix operator
id=<<[A|C]         -- even shorter but might conflict with other infix operators
[x|C,x<-A]         -- same length and no-conflict-guarantee™
[0|C]>>A           -- shortest way, but needs surrounding parenthesis more often than not
do[0|C];A          -- longer but works in some places where the above would need parents
```

Examples: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150747/56433), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150784/56433)

Comment: The second one has `A` and `[]` switched.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Corrected, thanks!

Comment: Aha! But `*>` has higher fixity than `>>` (still a bit low for comfort.)

Comment: `do[0|C];A` could sometimes be useful. i.e `X++do[0|C];A`

Comment: @H.PWiz Good one, I added it to the list

Answer (score 15):

### Don't waste the "otherwise" guard

A final guard that's a catch-all `True` (shorter as `1>0`) can be used to bind a variable. Compare:

```haskell
... |1>0=1/(x+y)
... |z<-x+y=1/z

... |1>0=sum l-sum m
... |s<-sum=s l-s m
```

Since the guard is mandatory and is otherwise wasted, little is needed to make this worth it. It's enough to save a pair of parens or bind a length-3 expression that's used twice. Sometimes you can negate guards to make the final case be the expression that best uses a binding.

Answer (score 14):

Don't use backticks too often.
Backticks are a cool tool for making sections of prefix functions, but can sometimes be misused.

Once I saw someone write this subexpression:

```
(x`v`)
```

Although it is the same as just `v x`.

Another example is writing `` (x+1)`div`y ``
as opposed to `div(x+1)y`.

I see it happen around `div` and `elem` more often because these functions are usually used as infix in regular code.

Comment: Don't you mean making sections of *prefix* functions?

Comment: @Cyoce Yes, of course

Comment: Exception: making section of prefix functions are shorter than using flip. So `(\`elem\`"ABC")` instead of `flip elem"ABC"`

Answer (score 14):

## Use the cons operator (:)

when concatenating lists, if the first is of length 1 then use `:` instead.

```
a++" "++b
a++' ':b  -- one character shorter

[3]++l
3:l    -- three characters shorter
```

Comment: Worth noting that it's right associative, so you can keep using it for any number of single items at the beginning of the list, e.g. `1:2:3:x` rather than `[1,2,3]++x`.

Answer (score 14):

## Use [pattern guards](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pattern_guard)

They're shorter than a `let` or a lambda that deconstructs the arguments of a function you're defining. This helps when you need something like `fromJust` from `Data.Maybe`:

```
f x=let Just c=… in c
```

is longer than

```
f x=(\(Just c)->c)$…
```

is longer than

```
m(Just c)=c;f x=m$…
```

is longer than

```
f x|Just c<-…=c
```

In fact, they’re shorter even when binding a plain old value instead of deconstructing: see [xnor’s tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76749/3852).

Comment: Well, the lambda one doesn't need the dollar sign, and it seems this change makes the lengths of this and the next snippet the same

Comment: I'm assuming `e` isn't actually one token but a longer expression that needs `$` before it, which is usually the case.

Answer (score 14):

## Use GHC 8.4.1 (or later)

With the [Semigroup Monoid Proposal](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/Libraries/Proposals/SemigroupMonoid) and the release of [GHC 8.4.1](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/8.4.1-notes.html), `Semigroup` has been moved to the `Prelude`. This gives us:

```hs
(<>) :: Semigroup a => a -> a -> a
```

Now these might seem useless at first glance, but looking closer we notice that `Monoid a => (x -> a)` is an instance of `Monoid`<sup>1</sup>, in which case we have the implementation:

```hs
(f <> g) xs = f xs <> g xs
```

This can be quite useful with for example lists, knowing that `(<>)` is the same as `(++)` for lists. So we have for example:

```hs
(init <> reverse) [1,2,3] ≡ init [1,2,3] <> reverse [1,2,3]
                          ≡ [1,2] <> [3,2,1]
                          ≡ [1,2] ++ [3,2,1]
                          ≡ [1,2,3,2,1]
```

However, this is not the only useful case: Knowing that `[x] -> [x]` is an instance of `Monoid`, we also have `a -> [x] -> [x]` an instance of `Monoid` (you can iterate this as many times as you want):

```hs
(drop <> take) 2 [1,2,3,4,5] ≡ (drop 2 <> take 2) [1,2,3,4,5]
                             ≡ drop 2 [1,2,3,4,5] <> take 2 [1,2,3,4,5]
                             ≡ [3,4,5] <> [1,2]
                             ≡ [3,4,5,1,2]
```

<sub>1: Note that `Monoid a` \$\implies\$ `Semigroup a`.</sub>

### Overview what we gained so far

Using this trick we have these (not exhaustive) helpers, note that we can chain them:

```hs
duplicate    = id <> id
triple²      = id <> id <> id
palindromize = init <> reverse
rotateLeft   = drop <> take
removeElementAt = take <> drop . succ
removeNElementsAt n = take <> drop . (+n)
```

<sub>2: This could <s>also be `([1..3]>>)` for the same bytecount</s> be shorter (see comment by [Ørjan Johansen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66041/%C3%98rjan-johansen)).</sub>

### Where are the \$(\mathbb{Z},\texttt{+})\$ and \$(\mathbb{Z},\texttt{*})\$ monoids?

If we want to use the \$(\mathbb{Z},\texttt{+})\$ monoid, we need to tell GHC that. It can not decide for us which one it should use, therefore there are two `newtype`s which allow this - `Sum` and `Product`.

Given that the consensus is [to allow implicitly typed functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11223/untyped-functions-in-static-languages/12747#12747), we are probably allowed to do so if the challenge does not talk about a specific implementation for integers. Using this we can for example write \$n\$th [oblong number](https://oeis.org/A002378) as

```hs
id<>(+1)
```

which is shorter than `f n=n*(n-1)` or even `(*)=<<succ`/`(*)<*>succ`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY8xT8NADIX3@xVPVYdEkFO7RmkmFoYKpA4MBCHT3KUnkjvr4gj1zxOutBlgsAe/7/nZJxo/Td/PbuAQBQ8kpPfBB9ciw3MM7XSUTOv8HllV58iVUhZluUh49GI6E1HU/0fK7prZtVWd3W3zeSDnsUMbFFAUeInEcFdwBI2LuZAzG5BvQcz9GTbhA/H@HRnHxEPDprrROV43Wm83b@q69UCDwcckoH4MmPzXJUVOZoANERyNiEu3hkl4kmRJ/SARq8Y/xRvOpi0bWV3E37w1OiPLZ3/CUa3rJX/@PtqeunEujsw/)<sup>3</sup>

<sub>3: Note that we need to use `(+1)` and cannot use `succ` since GHC can't know that there is an instance of `Enum`.</sub>

### Other noteworthy related tricks

Instances that might be useful not covered above:

```hs
()
Ordering
(Monoid a, Monoid b) => Monoid (a,b)  -- (also 3-,4- and 5-tuples)
Monoid a => Monoid (IO a)
Ord k => Monoid (Map k v)             -- from Data.Map
```

---

It might be worth noting that there is `mconcat` too:

```hs
mconcat [f1,f2,…,fN] ≡ f1 <> f2 <> … <> fN
```

This will probably not be useful often, for it needs at least \$3-11\$ functions (depending on the need of parentheses, see comments), but it might be in case you have some list `Monoid a => [a]` already.

---

Furthermore `mempty` can be useful since it is shorter than `Nothing` or even `pure Nothing`, `([],[])` etc.

---

Another useful instance is `Monoid a => Monoid (IO a)` which has successfully been used for the currently [shortest quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161036/48198) as

```hs
(putStr <> print) "foo" ≡ putStr "foo" <> print "foo"
                        ≡ do x <- putStr "foo"
                             y <- print "foo"
                             pure $ x <> y
                        ≡ do putStr "foo"
                             print "foo"
                             pure ()
                        ≡ putStr "foo" >> print "foo"
```

Comment: `("123">>)` is shorter.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: Ah damn, it was meant for educational purposes :P (showing that you can join multiple functions, not only two)

Comment: By my count 8−11 functions should be 4−11. (Best case if *all* functions need parentheses with `<>`.)

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: [That](https://tio.run/##hcxNCoJQGAXQ@beSgiv4/BesjYiDh3gp8mmkkwjX/rorqMGZnpvfHtM8x08ST3TdlZnkUkgpldTSnC2M6zL6vacDMzAHC7AEK7AGm8FsfZn9XqSVVNy/EGzBFHRDTI7g78slTOG5v@MX "Haskell – Try It Online")'s how I counted (ie. not assuming anything about the `f`s, but I should probably have written 9-11 or 8-10 to keep it consistent. I adjusted it to 4-11 (sounds better, though it's still a lot).

Comment: Oh, I thought of parentheses around each individual function, but I did not consider parentheses around the whole. In that case it can beat it with 3: `mconcat[f1,f2,f3]` is a byte shorter than `((f1)<>(f2)<>(f3))`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: If someone actually needs all these parens, maybe they should switch to LISP ^^ Seriously though, a lot of times the outer parentheses are needed, unfortunately. And it's a fair point with the inner parentheses, with the list one does not need to shy away from using `($)`.

Comment: I think you meant `Monoid a => Monoid (IO a)`. The second `Monoid` is missing.

Comment: @dfeuer: Yes, you're right that was a typo. Fixed it, thank you for carefully reading through it :)

Answer (score 13):

## Shorter syntax for local declarations

Sometimes you need to define a local function or operator, but it costs lots of bytes to write `where` or `let…in` or to lift it to top-level by adding extra arguments.

```haskell
g~(a:b)=2!g b where k!l=k:take(a-1)l++(k+1)!drop(a-1)l
g~(a:b)=let k!l=k:take(a-1)l++(k+1)!drop(a-1)l in 2!g b
g~(a:b)=2!g b$a;(k!l)a=k:take(a-1)l++((k+1)!drop(a-1)l)a
```

Fortunately, Haskell has a confusing and seldom-used but reasonably terse syntax for [local declarations](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-460003.13):

```haskell
fun1 pattern1 | let fun2 pattern2 = expr2 = expr1
```

In this case:

```haskell
g~(a:b)|let k!l=k:take(a-1)l++(k+1)!drop(a-1)l=2!g b
```

You can use this syntax with multi-statement declarations or multiple declarations, and it even nests:

```haskell
fun1 pattern1 | let fun2 pattern2 = expr2; fun2 pattern2' = expr2' = expr1
fun1 pattern1 | let fun2 pattern2 = expr2; fun3 pattern3 = expr3 = expr1
fun1 pattern1 | let fun2 pattern2 | let fun3 pattern3 = expr3 = expr2 = expr1
```

It also works for binding variables or other patterns, though [pattern guards](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54684/39242) tend to be shorter for that unless you’re also binding functions.

Comment: This also works inside list comprehensions: `[f 1|let f x=x+1]`.

Answer (score 12):

## Lambda parsing rules

A lambda-expression doesn't actually need parentheses around it - it just rather greedily grabs everything so the whole thing still parses, e.g. until

- a closing paren - `(foo$ \x -> succ x)`
- an in - `let a = \x -> succ x in a 4`
- the end of the line - `main = getContents>>= \x -> head $ words x`
- etc..

is encountered, and there are some weird edge-cases where this can save you a byte or two. I believe `\` can also be used to define operators, so when exploiting this you will need a space when writing a lambda directly after an operator (like in the third example).

[Here is an example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32757/etaoin-shrdlu-golf/32771#32771) of where using a lambda was the shortest thing I could figure out. The code basically looks like:

```hs
a%f=...
f t=sortBy(% \c->...)['A'..'Z']
```

Answer (score 12):

### Try rearranging function definitions and/or arguments

You can sometimes save a couple of bytes by changing the order of pattern-matching cases in a function definition.
These savings are cheap, but easy to overlook.

As an example, consider the following earlier version of (a part of) [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58605/32014):

```hs
(g?x)[]=x
(g?x)(a:b)=g(g?x$b)a
```

This is a recursive definition of `?`, with the base case being the empty list.
Since `[]` is not a useful value, we should swap the definitions and replace it with the wildcard `_` or a dummy argument `y`, saving a byte:

```hs
(g?x)(a:b)=g(g?x$b)a
(g?x)y=x
```

From the same answer, consider this definition:

```hs
f#[]=[]
f#(a:b)=f a:f#b
```

The empty list occurs in the return value, so we can save two bytes by swapping the cases:

```hs
f#(a:b)=f a:f#b
f#x=x
```

Also, the order of function arguments can sometimes make a difference by allowing you to remove unnecessary whitespace. Consider an earlier version of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60833/32014):

```hs
h p q a|a>z=0:h p(q+2)(a-1%q)|1<2=1:h(p+2)q(a+1%p)
```

There's an annoying piece of whitespace between `h` and `p` in the first branch.
We can get rid of it by defining `h a p q` instead of `h p q a`:

```hs
h a p q|a>z=0:h(a-1%q)p(q+2)|1<2=1:h(a+1%p)(p+2)q
```

Answer (score 12):

### Working with the minus sign

The minus sign `-` is an annoying exception to many syntax rules.
This tip lists some short ways of expressing negation and subtraction in Haskell.
Please let me know if I've missed something.

#### Negation

- To negate an expression `e`, just do `-e`. For example, `-length[1,2]` gives `-2`.
- If `e` is even moderately complex, you will need parentheses around `e`, but you can usually save a byte by moving them around: `-length(take 3 x)` is shorter than `-(length$take 3 x)`.
- If `e` is preceded by `=` or an infix operator of [fixity](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#fixity) less than 6, you need a space: `f= -2` defines `f` and `k< -2` tests if `k` is less than `-2`. If the fixity is 6 or greater, you need parens: `2^^(-2)` gives `0.25`. You can usually rearrange stuff to get rid of these: for example, do `-k>2` instead of `k< -2`.
- Similarly, if `!` is an operator, then `-a!b` is parsed as `(-a)!b` if the fixity of `!` is at most 6 (so `-1<1` gives `True`), and `-(a!b)` otherwise (so `-[1,2]!!0` gives `-1`). The default fixity of user-defined operators and backticked functions is 9, so they follow the second rule.
- To turn negation into a function (to use with `map` etc), use the section `(0-)`.

#### Subtraction

- To get a function that subtracts `k`, use the section `(-k+)`, which adds `-k`. `k` can even be a pretty complex expression: `(-2*length x+)` works as expected.
- To subtract 1, use `pred` instead, unless it would require a space on both sides. This is rare and usually happens with `until` or a user-defined function, since `map pred x` can be replaced by `pred<$>x` and `iterate pred x` by `[x,x-1..]`. And if you have `f pred x` somewhere, you should probably define `f` as an infix function anyway. See [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19259/32014).

Answer (score 11):

### Use `,` instead of `&&` in guards

Multiple conditions in a guard that all have to hold can be combined with `,` instead of `&&`.

```
f a b | a/=5 && b/=7 = ...
f a b | a/=5 ,  b/=7 = ...
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be conditions either, you can do things like this:
`f xs m | [x] <- xs, Just y <- m, x > 3 = y`

Answer (score 11):

### Get suffixes

Use `scanr(:)[]` to get the suffixes of a list:

```
λ scanr(:)[] "abc"
["abc","bc","c",""]
```

This is much shorter than `tails` after `import Data.List`. You can do prefixes with `scanr(\_->init)=<<id` (found by Ørjan Johansen).

```
λ  scanr(\_->init)=<<id $ "abc"
["","a","ab","abc"]
```

This saves a byte over

```
scanl(\s c->s++[c])[]
```

Comment: Perhaps `scanl(flip(:))[] "abc"` = `["","a","ba","cba"]` is also worth mentioning – sometimes the prefixes being backwards doesn't matter.

Comment: Ørjan Johansen found a one-byte shorter alternative for prefixes: [`scanr(\_->init)=<<id`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177153/56433)

Answer (score 11):

## Avoid `repeat n`

```hs
-- 8 bytes, whitespace might be needed before and after
repeat n

-- 8 bytes, whitespace might be needed before
cycle[n]

-- 7 bytes, whitespace might be needed before and after, can be reused,
-- needs an assignment, n needs to be global
l=n:l;l

-- 7 bytes, never needs whitespace, n needs to derive from Enum,
-- n has to be short enough to be repeated twice
[n,n..]
```

Either of those four expressions will produce an infinite list of `n`'s.

It's a very specific tip but it can save up to **3** bytes!

Comment: If `n` is global, `l=n:l;l` is the same length and works for (some) longer expressions. (May need whitespace though.)

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I incorporated it into the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

### Bind using guards

When defining a named function, you can bind an expression to a variable in a guard. For example,

```haskell
f s|w<-words s=...
```

does the same as

```haskell
f s=let w=words s in ...
f s=(\w->...)$words s
```

Use this to save on repeated expressions. When the expression is used twice, it breaks even at length 6, though spacing and precedence issues can change that.

(In the example, if the original variable `s` is not used, it's shorter to do

```haskell
g w=...
f=g.words
```

but that's not true for binding more complex expressions.)

Comment: Isn’t this sort of a duplicate/special case of [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54684/3852)?

Comment: @Lynn Looking back, it's a special case, but when I read that answer, the `Just` example made me think it's for pattern-matching to extract from a container, rather than to store on an expression.

Comment: Extra note on this one because it came up in some code I was toying with: you can also bind functions this way. In particular, in the example given in this post one could do `f s|w<-words=...` and use `w` instead of `words` any number of times in the following code. This is obvious in hindsight since functions are as good as any other value in Haskell, but it may be something you wouldn't think of at first.

Answer (score 10):

## Shorter `transpose`

To use the `transpose` function `Data.List` has to be imported. If this is the only function needing the import, one can save a byte using the following `foldr` definition of `transpose`:

```hs
import Data.List;transpose
e=[]:e;foldr(zipWith(:))e
```

Note that the behaviour is only identical for a list of lists with the same length.

I successfully used this [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106587/56433).

Comment: If you know the exact size of the list `map((<$>[0..k]).(!!))` where `k` is the size will likely be shorter.

Comment: @WheatWizard As written, `map((<$>[0..k]).(!!))s` computes the identy of a list of lists `s`. The approach works if we switch `s` and `[0..k]`, but then `(!!)` needs to be flipped. I guess simply `[map(!!i)s|i<-[0..k]]` then beats the point-free approaches. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v1jBViE62lDHSMc4VifaRMdUxwxIm@tY6FjGxnJlA2WNuHITM/OAjJR8LoWCosy8EgUVhdzEAg0NGxW7aAM9vexYTT0NRUVNzWJM@WJNvbSczAKwNEQtQk00SJGiYqZmcU2mjS5ENvb/fwA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 10):

## Use `(0<$)` instead of `length` for comparisons

When testing if a list `a` is longer than a list `b`, one would usually write

```
length a>length b
```

However replacing each element of both lists with same value, e.g. `0`, and then comparing those two lists can be shorter:

```
(0<$a)>(0<$b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1HBViHaUMdIxziWKwnKjuXKTczMA3JS8rkUCooy80oUVBRyUvPSSzIUEu2gjCSElIaBjUqiph2IStL8/x8A)

The parenthesis are needed because `<$` and the comparison operators (`==`, `>`, `<=`, ...) have the same precedence level 4, though in some other cases they might not be needed, saving even more bytes.

Comment: I like: void a>void b
Unfortunately, the generic version is not imported by default. :-(

Answer (score 9):

### Replace `let` by lambda

This can usually shorten a lone auxiliary definition that can't be [bound with a guard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76749/32014) or defined globally for some reason. For example, replace

```hs
let c=foo a in bar
```

by the 3 bytes shorter

```hs
(\c->bar)$foo a
```

For multiple auxiliary definitions, the gain is probably smaller, depending on the number of definitions.

```hs
let{c=foo a;n=bar a}in baz
(\c n->baz)(foo a)$bar a

let{c=foo a;n=bar a;m=baz a}in qux
(\c n m->qux)(foo a)(bar a)$baz a

let{c=foo a;n=bar a;m=baz a;l=qux a}in quux
(\c n m l->quux)(foo a)(bar a)(baz a)$qux a
```

If some of the definitions refer to the others, it is even harder to save bytes this way:

```hs
let{c=foo a;n=bar c}in baz
(\c->(\n->baz)$bar c)$foo a
```

The main caveat with this is that `let` allows you to define polymorphic variables, but lambdas do not, as noted by @ChristianSievers.
For example,

```hs
let f=length in(f["True"],f[True])
```

results in `(1,1)`, but

```hs
(\f->(f["True"],f[True]))length
```

gives a type error.

Comment: It rarely matters, but "semantically equivalent" promises a bit too much. We have polymorpic `let`, so we can do `let f=id in (f 0,f True)`. If we try to rewrite this with lambda it doesn't type check.

Comment: @ChristianSievers That's true, thanks for the note. I edited it in.

Answer (score 9):

## Lambdabot Haskell

A language is defined by its implementation, and lambdabot (the IRC bot over at #haskell) imports a ton of common modules by default. No need to spend precious bytes re-implementing your favorite functions from `Data.List` or `Control.Monad`, just write `Haskell (Lambdabot)` instead of `Haskell` in the title and you're good to go!

**Edit:**
[Here's a list of stuff that it imports by default](https://github.com/lambdabot/lambdabot/blob/1d1ed3e7980081c9f356f8d2fd8ca2771c0ed4f4/lambdabot/State/Pristine.hs.default), which includes, among other things, `Control.Arrow`, `Data.Bits`, `Data.Ratio`, `System.Random` and `{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}` - go wild!

Answer (score 9):

## Online Tools

- [**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/#haskell)
  TIO supports online compilation of Haskell code with the [GHC 8.0.2](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_8_0_2.html) compiler. As TIO is developed with code golfing in mind it's not just an online interpreter but also offers features like byte count, header and footer sections that do not count towards the total byte count (put your `main` and test code there), automatic markdown generation for a code golf submission, and more.
- [**pointfree.io**](http://pointfree.io/)
  Converts Haskell code to pointfree Haskell code which sometimes is shorter, see [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19260/56433).
  Note: When dealing with functions that take two or more arguments, the pointfree version generated by *pointfree.io* often includes the [`ap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:ap) function which is not in Prelude. However `<*>` is an equivalent inline version of `ap` and contained in Prelude in ghc 7.10 or higher. The same goes for [`liftM2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM2), which is also only available when importing `Control.Monad`. The pointfree version of some expression like `\x -> f (g x) (h x)` is given as `liftM2 f g h`, though this can equivalently be expressed as [`f.g<*>h`](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/66515?m=41076361#41076361).
- [**pointfree.pages.dev**](https://pointfree.pages.dev) is an alternative site for pointfree.io (which is down at the time of editing).
- [**Hoogle**](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/)

> Hoogle is a Haskell API search engine, which allows you to search many standard Haskell libraries by either function name, or by approximate type signature.

Useful to quickly search the documentation or lookup in which packages a function is included.

Comment: Note that TIO currently uses GHC 7.8, so the stuff in [this tip](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52949/32014) is not available.

Comment: @Zgarb I asked Dennis if ghc can be updated. Currently one can add `import Control.Applicative` and/or `import Control.Monad` into the header on TIO to use `<$>` ect.

Comment: @Zgarb TIO's ghc was updated to 8.0.2 thanks to Dennis.

Comment: TIOv2 Alpha was replaced with a fork of TIO Nexus, so GHC8.0.2 should be supported.

Answer (score 9):

## Avoid sorting

Haskell doesn't have a built-in sorting in Prelude. It can be accessed with an import:

```hs
import Data.List
sort
```

This also gives you access to functions like `sortOn` and `sortBy`, as well as other functions in [Data.List](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List.html). But, many times you don't need the full power of sorting and can make do without an import.

**Check if a list is sorted**

```hs
scanl1 max l==l
```

This requires the list to be nonempty. As a pointfree predicate:

```hs
(==)=<<scanl1 max
```

You can likewise check if a list is in descending order with `scanr1 max l==l`.

**Sort values lying in a known range**

If you know the `l` contains only, say, digits `0` to `9`, you can sort it as:

```hs
[d|d<-[0..9],x<-l,x==d]
```

This allows for duplicates in `l`. If you know `l` doesn't have duplicates, or are fine dropping them, you can do:

```hs
[d|d<-[0..9],elem d l]
```

or

```hs
filter(`elem`l)[0..9]
```

These also works if `l` is a string, enumerating characters as `['\0'..]` or `[' '..]`. The range of characters is very large but bounded.

**Min and max**

If you just need the smallest or largest element, `minimum` or `maximum` will do. You can also check whether `n>=maximum l` as `all(<=n)l`, and similarly for `minimum`.

**Sorted index**

One use of sorting is to find the index of some value `n` in sorted order within `l`. You can instead do that by counting smaller elements:

```hs
sum[1|x<-l,x<n]
```

If `x` appears more than once, this gives the index of its first appearance in sorted order.

Answer (score 8):

When writing expressions that don't use variables, you don't need to include the function name for scoring purpose. For example:

```
f=foo.bar
```

If `f` is the golfing answer, the byte count is 7 (you can omit `f=`). It is possible to write it properly with TIO using `CPP`.

In the header, include:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
f=\
```

[Example here.](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyflfraus4OPo5x7q6O6q4BwQoKCsW8tVYRvzPzq6zEpDXUHdRiXaUE8vMalYIS9Ws6bMRlfJ0MjYxNTM3MLSQCnWzs42M6Umz0Y3WtdCT88iNvZ/bmJmnoKtQkFpSXBJkU@egopCaV5OZl5qsULFfwA)

Comment: Golfier: Add a `-cpp` compiler flag.

Answer (score 8):

## (Ab)use the Reader Monad/Applicative

There already are comments on [pointfree code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144658/42833) and one mentioning `pure`, but I figured I'd make a specific tip for this since I see it a lot.

The Applicative functions in `Prelude` by default when specialized to functions are as follows

```
instance Applicative ((->) a) where
    pure = const
    (f <*> g) x = f x (g x)
```

Note that for this particular type, `(=<<)` acts almost the same as `(<*>)`, except it takes its second argument flipped (thanks @ØrjanJohansen).

`pure` is one character shorter than `const`, as mentioned elsewhere. The especially useful combinator, however, is `(<*>)`. Below are examples of where I've used it recently.

## [Unique characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188695/42833)

The straightforward way to solve this is

```
import Data.List
map(\x->(x!!0,length x)).group.sort
```

But we're here for codegolf, not readable code.

```
import Data.List
map((,).nub<*>length).group.sort
```

## A contrived function

This comes from a function my coworker wrote that I (unashamedly) golfed until it was unreadable.

Suppose we have

```
data Ex a b c
  = Ex
    { foo :: [(a,b)]
    , bar :: c}
```

and we want the natural implementation of a function

```
f :: Ex a b c -> [(a,c)]
```

I don't have the original solution (it did involve `(&&&)` from `Control.Arrow`, though), but the golfed one using `(<*>)` is

```
map.fmap.pure.bar<*>foo
```

which also abuses the `Functor` instance of `(,) a`.

## `digitSum(n) + n`

This golf is part of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188639/42833).

This is a pretty well-golfed function

```
\n->n+sum[read[d]|d<-show n]
```

but if we do away with readability and bring in `(<*>)`, we can shave off a character:

```
foldr((+).read.pure)<*>show
-- = \x -> foldr ((+) . read . pure) x (show x)
```

## do notation

If your function is of the form `\x -> (expr) x` and `(expr)` contains some repeated `blah x` often, you can sometimes save bytes with Reader monad `do` notation and `b<-blah`.

Here are some strange examples:

```
\x->max(div x 3*div x 5^div x 7)x   -- original expression
f x|d<-div x=max(d 3*d 5^d 7)x;f    -- define f=... then use f
\x->max(x!3*x!5^x^7)x;(!)=div       -- define (!)=div
do d<-div;max$d 3*d 5^d 7           -- aha!

\x->product x:filter(/=product x)x      -- original expression
(:)<$>product<*>(filter=<<(/=).product) -- yeah, no...
f x|p<-product x=p:filter(/=p)x;f       -- define f=... then use f
\x->p x:filter(/=p x)x;p=product        -- define p=product
do p<-product;(p:).filter(/=p)          -- aha!
```

In general, `do a<-b;c<-d;e` is equivalent to `\x->let{a=b x;c=d x}in e x`.

Comment: Using `=<<` instead of `<*>` gives a different parameter order that is sometimes useful.

Comment: `(<*>)` is the S combinator; `pure` is the K combinator.

Answer (score 8):

## The function `0^x`

This maps positive integers to `0` and zero to `1`. So, it acts a little bit like `!x` in C-like languages.

It crashes for negative `x`; in this case you can write `0^x^2`, which parses as `0^(x^2)`.

This is not technically specific to Haskell, but Haskell is quite strict about converting between numbers and booleans compared to some other common code golf languages. It's often shorter to use `0^x` and stay in `Integer`-land than to check `x==0`.

Even expressions like `0^(x-42)^2` come in handy sometimes (`if x==42 then 1 else 0`).

Example:

```hs
if x==0 then 'B' else 'A'
last$'B':['A'|x==0]
"AB"!!sum[1|x==0]
"AB"!!(0^x^2)
"AB"!!(0^x)       -- if x is never negative
```

Comment: If you need to use the arbitrary precision `Integer` type, it appears that `0^x` can also convert `x` from `Integer` to `Int` for use with `(!!)`

Answer (score 7):

### Partition a string with `mapM` and `words`

This function computes all partitions of a given string into nonempty contiguous substrings:

```
map(words.concat).mapM(\c->[[c],c:" "])
```

The idea is that the `mapM` non-deteministically replaces each character `c` with either `"c"` or `"c "`, and the resulting lists are concatenated and split at spaces.
There are two gotchas: the string must not contain spaces (if it contains spaces but not line breaks, use `"\n"` and `lines` for one extra byte), and each partition occurs twice in the resulting list (with and without a trailing space, which gets eaten by `words`).

I've used this technique a couple of times (at least [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/73305/find-the-missing-number-in-an-undelimited-string/73321#73321), [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/98252/pairable-strings/98271#98271) and [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/45496/insertspacesbetweenwords/45498#45498)).
It's pretty flexible, since you can apply more functions after `words` to modify the partitions, and/or replace `map` with another iteration function, like `any`.

Comment: Great idea using string function to split! I'll have to use this sometime. The best general-purpose alternative I found was 45 bytes, 6 longer: `foldr(\h t->map([h]:)t++[(h:y):z|y:z<-t])[[]]`.

Comment: When applied directly to some `x` this can be slightly shortened to `words.concat<$>mapM(\c->[[c],c:" "])x` .

Answer (score 7):

## Use `fromEnum` instead of `ord`

`fromEnum` is already available in `Prelude`, while `ord` needs to be imported from `Data.Char`. This will save you 12 bytes. With subsequent usages you should define an alias like `f=fromEnum` and use `f`.

Comment: If you use it more than once, you should define an alias with `e=fromEnum`, which is shorter than `import Data.Char` and costs 1 byte to use.

Comment: @Zgarb: of course, I'm always doing that when writing answers, but for this tip I totally forgot about it.

Comment: The same goes for `chr` and `toEnum`, however the type of `toEnum` needs to be forced from context.

Answer (score 7):

## Converting to Pointfree

As @Laikoni [mentioned in this post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107238/24877), you can use [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io/) to convert your code to pointfree code. However, if you want to do this conversion manually you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29596461/2913106) on stackoverflow by [@luqui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33796/luqui), which provides an algorithm:

> You need the following combinators, which are in the standard library.
>   I have also given their standard names from combinator calculus.
>
> ```hs
> id :: a -> a                                   -- I
> const :: a -> b -> a                           -- K
> (.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)        -- B
> flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a -> c)         -- C
> (<*>) :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -- S
> ```
>
> Work with one parameter at a time.  Move parameters on the left to
>   lambdas on the right, e.g.
>
> ```hs
> f x y = Z
> ```
>
> becomes
>
> ```hs
> f = \x -> \y -> Z
> ```
>
> I like to do this one argument at a time rather than all at once, it
>   just looks cleaner.
>
> Then eliminate the lambda you just created according to the following
>   rules. I will use lowercase letters for literal variables, uppercase
>   letters to denote more complex expressions.
>
> 1. If you have `\x -> x`, replace with `id`
> 2. If you have `\x -> A`, where `A` is any expression in which `x` does not occur, replace with `const A`
> 3. If you have `\x -> A x`, where `x` does not occur in `A`, replace with `A`. This is known as "eta contraction".
> 4. If you have `\x -> A B`, then
>
>    1. If `x` occurs in both `A` and `B`, replace with `(\x -> A) <*> (\x -> B)`.
>    2. If `x` occurs in just `A`, replace with `flip (\x -> A) B`
>    3. If `x` occurs in just `B`, replace with `A . (\x -> B)`,
>    4. If `x` does not occur in either `A` or `B`, well, there's another rule we should have used already.
>
> And then work inward, eliminating the lambdas that you created.

Sometimes a shortcut with `>>=` is possible:

5. If you have `\x -> A B x`, where `x` does not occur in `A`, replace with `(\x -> B) >>= A`.

Comment: in the general case, `(\x -> A B x) = join ((\x -> A) <*> (\x -> B))`.

Comment: @Razetime thanks for the suggestion, it already is mentioned:)

Answer (score 7):

### Cheap divisors

The usual way to get the divisors (factors) of `n` is:

```haskell
[d|d<-[1..n],mod n d<1]
```

For example, `n=6` gives `[1,2,3,6]`. But, if you're OK with divisors repeating out of order, you can just do:

```haskell
gcd n<$>[1..n]
```

For `n=6`, this gives `[1,2,3,2,1,6]`. The code is effectively `[gcd k n|k<-[1..n]]`, takes the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20greatest%20common,8%20and%2012%20is%204.) of `k` with `n`. These are by definition divisors of `n`, and each divisor `d` appears at least once as `gcd d n`. So, the "set" of divisors is correct. The first appearances are in increasing order, so [removing duplicates](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Unique-0.4.7.8/docs/Data-List-Unique.html) will match the original code's result.

Answer (score 6):

## Define local variables in list comprehensions using singleton lists

For example, rather than writing

```hs
[x+y|x<-[1..5],let y=2]
```

one can write

```hs
[x+y|x<-[1..5],y<-[2]]
```

for a byte less.

This works in `do` blocks as well, but only in the list context since the `[]` syntactic sugar is necessary to come out ahead. (I guess any custom monads with single-letter constructors would benefit from this, too, but I don't think I've ever seen any of those show up in code golf.)

Comment: @Brute_Force: I meant only to show an example of how this tip would be used; I did not mean to claim that this particular example is realistic. For a more realistic example, consider `\a b->[[r..s]|r<-[a..b],s<-[2*r+7],s>7]`

Answer (score 6):

## Powerset

The "canonical" way of computing the powerset of a list is `Data.List.subsequences`.
If it is used only once and applied to a value (as opposed to, say, being fed to `map`), it's slightly shorter to implement it yourself.
Compare:

```
import Data.List;subsequences x
concat<$>mapM(\a->[[a],[]])x
```

This saves 0-3 bytes depending on whether you need a space between `subsequences` and the argument, and whether the latter expression needs parentheses around it.
If `x` has the form `f<$>y`, you can move `f` inside the lambda to save some more bytes, particularly if `f` is also defined by a lambda:

```
import Data.List;subsequences$f<$>y
concat<$>mapM(\a->[[f a],[]])y

import Data.List;subsequences$(\a->a*3+1)<$>y
concat<$>mapM(\a->[[a*3+1],[]])y
```

It's also possible to compose `concat` with another function, if you intended to map it over the subsequences anyway:

```
import Data.List;g<$>subsequences x
g.concat<$>mapM(\a->[[a],[]])x
```

If you have already imported `Control.Monad`, you can implement the powerset function in 18-20 bytes with one of

```
filterM(\_->[0>1..])
filterM$[0>1..]<$id
filterM([0>1..]<$f)
filterM$[0>1..]<$f
```

The last two variants need another function `f :: a -> b` to be defined, where `[a]` is the type of the list (doesn't matter what `f` does or what `b` is).
The optimal choice depends on whether such an `f` is available, and whether you need parentheses around the expression.

Comment: Might note that this gives 3 different variations in the ordering of the resulting power set. `subsequences` uses the order that generalizes to an infinite list, although then it's not really a power set.

Comment: Maybe it has some use in some situation `(\a->[[a],[]])` has the same length as the point free `((:[[]]).pure)`.

Answer (score 5):

## Use [`Data.Lists`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lists-0.4.2/docs/Data-Lists.html)

This package defines a lot of nice functions on lists! It’s like `Data.List` in `base`, but fancier.

Importing it costs 18 bytes (`import Data.Lists\n`).

Here are some nice things it exports, **on top of everything from `Data.List`**:

```
Various shortcuts:

  for              ≡ flip map
  unionOf          ≡ foldr union []
  hasAny e x       ≡ any (`elem` e) x
  countElem i      ≡ length . filter (== i)
  list b f xs      ≡ if null xs then b else f xs
  firstOr x        ≡ list x head
  maxList xs       ≡ list 0 maximum
  catchNull f      ≡ list Nothing (Just . f)
  lastToMaybe      ≡ catchNull last
  chop f           ≡ list [] (\x->let (y,ys)=f x in y:chop f ys)
  pair x y         ≡ guard (length x == length y) >> Just (zip x y)
  pairWith f x y   ≡ guard (length x == length y) >> Just (zipWith f x y)

Split functions:

  splitOn "x" "axbxc"                  ≡ ["a","b","c"]
  endBy ";" "foo;bar;baz;"             ≡ ["foo","bar","baz"]
  splitWhen (<0) [1,3,-4,5,7,-9,0,2]   ≡ [[1,3],[5,7],[0,2]]
  splitOneOf ";.," "foo,bar;baz.gluk"  ≡ ["foo","bar","baz","gluk"]
  endByOneOf ";.," "ae;io.,u,"         ≡ ["ae","io","","u"]
  chunk 3 ['a'..'k']                   ≡ ["abc","def","ghi","jk"]
  replace old new                      ≡ intercalate new . splitOn old

Variants of Data.List functions:

  elemRIndex     ∷ a -> [a] -> Maybe Int   (Rightmost index)
  powerslice     ∷ [a] → [[a]]             (All slices of a list)

  spanList       ∷ ([a] → Bool) → [a] → ([a], [a])
  breakList      ∷ ([a] → Bool) → [a] → ([a], [a])
  takeWhileList  ∷ ([a] → Bool) → [a] → [a]
  dropWhileList  ∷ ([a] → Bool) → [a] → [a]

Data.List.Argmax:

  argmin,         argmax           ∷ Ord b ⇒ (a → b) → [a] →   a
  argmins,        argmaxes         ∷ Ord b ⇒ (a → b) → [a] →  [a]
  argminWithMin,  argmaxWithMax    ∷ Ord b ⇒ (a → b) → [a] → ( a,  b)
  argminsWithMin, argmaxesWithMax  ∷ Ord b ⇒ (a → b) → [a] → ([a], b)

Association list functions: treat [(k, v)] as a pseudo-map type.

  delFromAL l k  ≡ filter ((/= k) . fst) l
  addToAL l k v  ≡ (k, v) : delFromAL l k
  keysAL         ≡ map fst
  hasKeyAL k     ≡ any ((== k) . fst)
  flipAL         ∷ [(k, v)] → [(v, [k])]
```

Answer (score 5):

## Integral to Fractional (e.g. Int to Double)

Instead of using the famous

```hs
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

in many cases

```hs
realToFrac :: (Real a, Fractional b) => a -> b
```

works too. and is two bytes shorter.

Comment: There are cases where `read.show` works too, if GHC can infer the types. (For example: `sin$read$show someInt`.)

Comment: `toEnum :: Enum a => Int -> a` also works, though slightly more constrained.

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell + `plumbers`

Use the [plumbers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/plumbers-0.0.3) package for a large collection of infix combinators.

For example,

```hs
-- Ungolfed
f (x, y) (z, t) = (x + z, y + t)
-- Golfed (without plumbers)
f(x,y)(z,t)=(x+z,y+t)
-- Golfed (with plumbers)
f=(+)***(+)
```

Or, let's say we wanted to find the dot product of a list of vectors in the form `[(Double, Double)]`.

```hs
-- Ungolfed
g = sum . map (\(x,y) -> x * y)
-- Golfed (without plumbers)
g=sum.map(uncurry(*))
-- Golfed (with plumbers)
g=sum.map((*)$*id)
```

Plumbers are a great way to pointfree an expression, especially in the middle of a map or a fold.

As a quick note, the way to read these operators is as follows.

```hs
($**>^)
```

Every plumber takes two functions as arguments. The first character specifies how to combine the results of the two functions. A `*` means to return a tuple, and a `$` means to pass the result of the second function to the first function. The remaining characters specify what to do with the remaining arguments.

```
< Pass the argument to the left but not the right function
> Pass the argument to the right but not the left function
& Pass the argument to both functions
^ Ignore the argument completely
* The argument is a tuple; split it and pass the parts to the left and right functions
```

Comment: I like how plumbers calls itself ***pointless** plumbing combinators*.

Answer (score 5):

## Helper functions

This is (or will) be a list of generic helper functions that occasionally have to be implemented as part of a bigger solution.

- Primality test: `p :: Int -> Bool`

  ```
  p n=mod(product[1..n-1]^2)n>0
  ```
- Binary to decimal: `b :: String -> Int`

  ```
  b=foldl(\a x->2*a+read[x])0
  ```
- Decimal to binary: `d :: Int -> String`

  ```
  d n=mapM(\_->"01")[1..n]!!n
  ```

More to come.

Comment: It might be worth adding two more primality tests: `p n=[1|0<-mod n<$>[2..n]]==[1]` and `p n=all((>0).mod n)[2..n-1]`. The former identifies `0` as not prime, the latter is only valid for `n>=2`. Both can come in handy

Comment: Also the `^2` in the primality test is only needed for `n==4`.

Comment: The decimal to binary can be `d n=mapM("01"<$d)[1..n]!!n`, although that depends on defining it as a function, or having another one-letter `Int->something` function to put with the `<$`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, some of those tests look similar to Wilson's theorem, but not the same. Where's the square come from?

Comment: @dfeuer It's the shortest way to handle the fact that Wilson's product for the number n=4 is 2 (mod n), instead of 0 (mod n) like for all other composites.

Comment: The decimal to binary can be further reduced to `d=(mapM("01"<$d)[1..8]!!)` if your input is an ASCII character.

Answer (score 5):

#### Use `pure` to build singletons

- `pure` is one byte shorter than `(:[])` or `Right` (thanks, Ørjan Johansen).
- `pure.f` is one byte shorter than `Just .f`.
- `pure` is shorter than `singleton` if you need `Data.Sequence` for some reason.
- As Ørjan Johansen points out, this works for the writer monad: `pure a=(mempty,a)`. This may occasionally be useful for something like `(Nothing, a)`.

Comment: `(,)mempty` popped into my mind as another example... not sure how useful.

Comment: Oh, and `Right` too.

Answer (score 5):

## Binary op on two-element list

You can apply a binary operation to a two-element list like:

```
foldr1(-)[5,3]
```

to get `5-3`, or `2`. Note that this operator must output the same type as the input, that is be `a -> a -> a`. So, `foldr1(==)[5,3]` doesn't typecheck but `foldr1 mod[5,3]` does.

You can think of this as a list analogue to `uncurry(-)(5,3)`. It may be useful if you take input as a two-element list or one is produced in an intermediate computation, and it would cost extra bytes to match it to `[a,b]` to extract the values.

Using `foldl1` gives the same result as `foldr1`. The best way to flip the order of the operands seems to just be to `flip` the operator.

Answer (score 4):

### Fixity declarations are your friends

As we know it is often cheaper to define an operator instead of a function (see [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19259/56433)), sometimes it pays off to declare a fixity different from the default (`infixl 9`). Imagine for example the following which is fairly common (57 bytes):

```
(a:b)!(c:d)=undefined
(a:b)!e=undefined
e!(a:b)=undefined
```

In that particular case using a fixity declaration is still 1 byte more expensive (58 bytes):

```
infix 4!
a:b!c:d=undefined
a:b!e=undefined
e!a:b=undefined
```

As you can see you can use the low fixity to omit several parentheses, if somewhere in your code you have other parentheses that are due to the high default fixity, you can save bytes for these by declaring another fixity.

---

**Note:** This might seem like an arbitrary example but it is realistic as you can see in [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154348/48198) answer.

Comment: [Here's another answer that uses this trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240873/56656).

Answer (score 4):

Use `pure` instead of `const`. I saw this in someone else's answer, but I don't know where. Of course, it's often better to use a lambda if it's applied.

There's an occasional one byte shorter trick than the lambda `\_->x`: Use `x<$f` where `f` is any one-letter function that just happens to have the same input type as what you want. Note that this never evaluates `f` itself at all.

Answer (score 3):

### fmap

In the spirit of saving characters using infix operators, you could save a couple by replacing something like:

```
map show [1..9]
```

with:

```
show<$>[1..9]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Use `zip`

Often you need to map over a list and apply some function which depends on the index of the argument in the list. while a lot of impure languages who have some sort of `map` builtin have the index be an optional argument, this is impossible in Haskell. instead, use:

```
mapWithIndex f xs === f<$>zip[0..]xs
                  === [f i x|(i,x)<-zip[0..]xs] {- inlinable version -}
                  === zipWith f[0..]xs
mapWithIndex f    === (f<$>).zip[0..]           {- points free version -}
```

(This also gives us 1-based indexing for free!)

Often this combines well within list comprehensions, where even a builtin `mapWithIndex` won't help:

```
    [ ... | ..., (i,x)<-zip[0..]xs, ...]
```

Other times, you really want to use the nonexistant equivalent `maximumOn` of `sortOn`, but the import is too many bytes, or using `maximumBy` is too many bytes too. instead, use*:

```
sortOn f xs === snd$sort$(f>>=(,))<$>xs
            === snd$sort[(f x,x)|x<-xs]   {- inlinable version -}
sortOn f    === snd.sort.(f>>=(,)<$>)     {- points free version -}
```

Note that sometimes you will need both the best `x` and its `f x`, in which case you can get rid of three bytes and have it computed for you for free!

many other uses for this combination are possible too.

Comment: I don't think `f<$>zip[0..]xs` works as `[f i x|(i,x)<-zip[0..]xs]`. You'd need `uncurry f<$>zip[0..]xs`, since `f` is being given tuples of `(i,x)`. It would work to do `zipWith f[0..]xs`,

Comment: @xnor as the code golfer, you can modify your `f` whatever way fits best. We're not writing library functions here.

Comment: @xnor Oh, that's a way I haven't thought of! I'll add it.

Comment: Oh, you're saying that `f` is the outer function that you're defining in the code golf challenge, and so you can choose whether it's curried or takes a tuple? That definitely works for that case, but it wasn't clear from reading it that it wasn't meant to apply to functions you define as as subpart of your golf.

Comment: @xnor even if `f`  isn't a function you defined yourself, then the fact that both options are possible is useful, because using `curry` or `uncurry` will probably be longer than just switching to one of the other options presented here.

Answer (score 3):

### Use empty `let` instead of `otherwise`/`True`

```
x&y|x=y|let=x  -- Boolean and
```

While it is no shorter than using `1>0` and usually it makes more sense to [use the guard to bind a variable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85910/69655) it can be useful when there are source restrictions or the prelude is not in scope.

This works because let statements in guards behave as always true and an empty let is valid.

Empty let also works in list comprehensions, but I believe it completely useless for golfing in that position as it can be omitted.

Answer (score 3):

## Pattern match inside list comprehensions

Suppose you have code that looks like (imports for purpose of demonstration)

```
import Data.List (lookup)
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)

ys = [(1,"a"), (3, "b"), (5, "c"), (7, "d")]
catMaybes [lookup x ys | x <- [1..10]]
```

You can change this to

```
[y | x <- [1..10], Just y <-[lookup x ys]]
```

I found it particularly helpful when I was
pattern matching in a function definition

```
f (x:xs) = [foo x x'| x' <-[1..10]]
f [] = []
```

when I could instead put the pattern matching logic inside the list comprehension.

```
f lst = [foo x x' | x:xs<-[lst], x'<-[1..10]]
```

This works because incomplete pattern matches are desuarged to `mfail`
instead of `error` in `do` notation, so for things like the list monad,
we get the empty list. It can be used with `do` notation for other
monads, too, although `pure` is probably the shortest alternative to `[]`.

```
f :: [Int] -> Maybe String
f lst = do
  1:xs <- pure lst
  pure "one"
```

Comment: Some notes: (1) `lookup` itself can be replaced by pattern matching if you know there cannot be more than one match. (2) You don't need parentheses around patterns before `<-`. (3) You can shorten `[foo x x' | (x:xs)<-[lst], x'<-[1..10]]` further to `[foo x|x:xs<-[lst]]<*>[1..10]`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen nice catch on the parentheses, and yeah I’m sure there are other tricks, these were contrived examples to demonstrate the utility.

Answer (score 3):

## `iterate` isn't very good

Defining your own function that returns an infinite list is *usually* shorter.
Compare:

```hs
f x=x*x+x;iterate f a
iterate(\x->x*x+x)a
g x=x:g(x*x+x);g a
```

Exceptions include when `f` is a builtin, but remember:

- `iterate pred a` is just `[a,pred a..]`
- `iterate(+k)a` is just `[a,a+k..]`

Sometimes I see people write very "Haskell-y" expressions like:

```hs
(+5).fst<$>iterate(\(a,b)->(b,a+b+1))(0,1)
```

But this can be golfed down all the way to:

```hs
a#b=b+5:b#(a+b+1);0#1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Endless `Char` ranges

You can use endless ranges of `Char`s, and they will still be finite, because there are only 1114111 valid Unicode characters:

```haskell
['a'..]
```

producing

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\DEL\128\129\130\131\132\133\134\135\136\137\138\139\140\141\142..."
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWW3ITM_MUbBUKijLzShSi1RPV9fRiIVJQFTCVAA)

In many cases where you would otherwise use a range such as `['a'..'z']`, you may be able to leave off the ending item, if you know the input is constrained to a certain set of characters (e.g. only alphanumeric ASCII)

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid Data.List

The function are nice, but imports are costly. If you only need a single function, there are shorter alternatives:

```haskell
import Data.List;intercalate -- too long
c#s=tail$(c:)=<<s            -- nice, especially when inlined
(tail.).(=<<).(:)            -- if you like unreadable mess
(tail.).((c:)=<<)            -- applied to c
```

```
import Data.List;intersperse -- too long
c#s=tail$do d<-s;[c,d]       -- nice
(c:).pure=<<tail             -- a function on the list
```

Check if the challenge allows for leading and/or trailing newlines. You may be able to omit the `tail`.