# The primitive circle problem

Tags: code-golf, geometry

## Challenge

The [primitive circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem#Generalizations) is the problem of determining how many  [coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime) integer lattice points \$x,y\$ there are in a circle centered at the origin and with radius \$r \in \mathbb{Z}^+
\$ such that \$x^2+y^2 \le r^2 \$. It's a generalization of [Code-Golf: Lattice Points inside a Circle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1938/code-golf-lattice-points-inside-a-circle).

[image: primitive_circle]

**Input**

Radius \$r \in \mathbb{Z}^+\$

**Output**

Number of coprime points

## Test Cases

Taken from sequence [A175341](https://oeis.org/A175341) in the [OEIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-Line_Encyclopedia_of_Integer_Sequences).

| Radius | Number of coprime points |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 16 |
| 4 | 32 |
| 5 | 48 |

Comment: It looks from your test cases that input may be considered to only be non-negative integers, but you don't explicitly state that - could you please confirm?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I truly hope that there is no circle with negative radius

Comment: @enzo, I'm not sure if your comment was just a bit of fun - my point was that it looks from the test cases like we don't need to handle an input like `5.7`, but the post does not clarify this.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yes! I was only joking about the fact that by explicitly saying "non-negative", it could look like that you were interested in negative integers as well. But the focus here is the numeric domain indeed, very interesting observation.

Comment: @JonathanAllan: I'm not sure decimal values make sense to begin with when considering prime factorization (which is inherently required to check if numbers are coprime). Prime numbers only exist within the space of positive integers.

Comment: @Flater but a larger (non-integer) radius may include more coprime (integer) lattice points. (Challenge has been updated stating that "Radius \$r \in \mathbb{Z}^+\$", so there is no issue anymore anyway.)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Fair point

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), 45 bytes

Based on [A000089](https://oeis.org/A000089), the number of solutions to:

$$x^2+1\equiv 0 \pmod n$$

which allows to compute [A304651](https://oeis.org/A304651) and eventually [A175341](https://oeis.org/A175341).

```javascript
f=(n,k=N=n*n)=>N&&4*(--k*k%N>N-2)+f(n,k||--N)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBDsIgEEDRfU8xi9owIEatu0qPwBlKKhiFDKZt3FDOjrj6m5f/Nl@zzsvrs0mKD1uKU4yOXmlFnFCNuutunEnpuT/oUcsrCvcH@y6lxuLiwoLdgEDBeai5w6WvFQIhNQBzpDUGewrxySbD2kQZK21TnWCecGhy@QE)

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 58 bytes

*-1 thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*

The recursion is convenient in JS but otherwise really pointless. It is replaced with a single loop below.

```c
k,N;f(n){for(k=N=n*n,n=0;N;k=k?:--N)n+=--k*k%N>N-2;k=4*n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BCsIwEEX3PcVQCCRNBkpxZYzeICdwE1JSyugoVXBRcnVjgqsH738@P@ISYylkvE2S1Z4emyTnHQ9s2I3WW3J0OSJ6xdoh0kDCnz1O1R8Gtrms/IZ7WFkq2DuANtAUg4PRVpxgatT6nwM8t5on2QcpZlVbYr5yb4ANtAfK1lLucvnGdAvLq@DnBw)

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 63 bytes

```c
f(m,r,n,x){for(r=n=0;n++<m*m;)for(x=n;x--;)r+=x*x%n>n-2;m=r*4;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBCsIwEADP7SuWSiFpEqnibZu@xIskRhfMVmKFQOnbY@tpYGaceThXDsTu9fV3GD6zp@n4HEsQUSfNOsslTEkky7ZHVmqIXUS5q2wZszEok7K5yy2PbM4YbeouuBbiGeKNWEhY6mr7QeyKwEKPGwY4bVSK/r16p60G0bQezAitv3KjgTQEQVJiXa31Wn4)

Port of [@enzo's python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269992/91267) (very surprised that it matches byte count with the python answer)

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 49 bytes

```
r4I~If[Abs@+##>r,Sign@r,#~#0~+##+#2~#0~+##]&~1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7v@j9pIUmnnWeadGOScUO2srKdkU6wZnpeQ5FOsp1ygZ1QBFtZSMoK1atzvB/QFFmXkm0sq5dmgNIIDg5Ma8uKDEvPTXaQMfEPPY/AA)

Counts edges of that star formed by the points in the first quadrant.

```
   I~                                       &~1   initial edge: 1-I
     If[Abs@+##>r,      ,                  ]      can this edge be split?
                         #~#0~+##+#2~#0~+##         yes: split the edge
                  Sign@r                            no: count if input≠0
  4                                               * 4 quadrants
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>70</s> 63 bytes

```python
lambda m:4*sum(x*x%n>n-2for n in range(m*m+1)for x in range(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHXykSruDRXo0KrQjXPLk/XKC2/SCFPITNPoSgxLz1VI1crV9tQEyRYgRDM09T8DxLKRAiZaVpxKQBBQVFmXolGmkYmUAkA)

- *-7 bytes* thank to Mukundan314 by removing the double sum and parenthesis

Comment: [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHXykSruDRXQ6NCq0LbUFM1z8YwLb9IIU8hM0@hKDEvPVUjVysXKAESrEAI5mlq/gcJZSKEzDStuBSAoKAoM69EI00jE6gEAA)

Comment: @Mukundan314 Yeah, no need for the double sum. Thanks!

Comment: doing `x*x%n>n-2` instead of `(x*x+1)%n<1` saves 2 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 61 bytes

```
f[n_]=Sum[Boole[GCD[x,y]==1&&x^2+y^2<=n^2],{x,-n,n},{y,-n,n}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z8tOi8@1ja4NDfaKT8/JzXa3dklukKnMtbW1lBNrSLOSLsyzsjGNi/OKFanukJHN08nr1anuhLCiP0fUJSZVxIdXAKk0oMy09KABoQkJgHJtOhMoIZMHQMdQ4vaWB0lBaXY2P8A)

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yc1L70kwyE4P6csNdrd2SW6QifW1tZQTc0vvyjXobpCp9bGVllBWcczryQ1PbWoOFbtf0BRZl5JtLKuXZqDcqxaXXByYl5dUGJeemq0gY6Jeex/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## Google Sheets, 109 bytes

```
=iferror(4*sum(map(sequence(1,A2+1,0),lambda(x,map(sequence(A2),lambda(y,(1=gcd(x,y))*(x^2+y^2<=A2^2)))))),0)
```

Put the radius in cell `A2` and the formula in cell `C2`.

The formula creates a \$(n+1)×n\$ matrix for the upper right quadrant, excluding the \$x\$ axis (\$y ≠ 0\$). The matrix contains ones and zeros. The result is 4 times the sum of the matrix.

[image: coprime lattice points.png]

This would be much simpler to implement with an array formula, but unfortunately `gcd()` is an aggregating function that only gives one result per evaluation rather than a result matrix, so we need to test every lattice point separately.

Comment: can the `iferror()` be removed to reduce -11 bytes?

Comment: Sure, but when radius is `0`, the formula would give `#N/A`, because `sequence()` errors out when its argument is less than `1`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 53 bytes

```
(k=0;Do[k+=4Tr[1^PowerModList[-1,1/2,n]],{n,#^2}];k)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277XyPb1sDaJT86W9vWJKQo2jAuIL88tcg3P8Uns7gkWtdQx1DfSCcvNlanOk9HOc6oNtY6W1Ptf0BRZl6Jgr5Dur5DUGJeemq0gY6hQez//wA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒRṗ2²S>ɗÐḟ²g/€ċ1
```

A monadic Link that accepts the non-negative integer<sup>*</sup> radius and yields the count of coprime lattice points in or on the circle of that radius centred at the origin.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//xZJS4bmXMsKyUz7Jl8OQ4bifwrJnL@KCrMSLMf///zU)**

#### How?

```
ŒRṗ2²S>ɗÐḟ²g/€ċ1 - Link: non-negative integer, r
ŒR               - abs-range -> [-r..r]
  ṗ2             - Cartesian power {2}
                    -> LatticePoints of the enclosing, axis-aligned square
        Ðḟ       - filter discard those {LatticePoints} for which:
       ɗ  ²      -   last three links as a dyad - f(LatticePoint, r^2)
    ²            -     square {each coordinate of LatticePoint}
     S           -     sum {these}
      >          -     {that} greater than {r^2}?
           g/€   - reduce each {remaining LatticPoint} by GCD
              ċ1 - {that} count occurrences of one
```

<sup>* Also works for floats, up to floating-point errors, since while `ŒR` implicitly floors its input no lattice point will be in or on the circle if one of its coordinates is further out.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 54 bytes

```
f(n)=sum(x=-n,n,sum(y=-n,n,gcd(x,y)==1&&x^2+y^2<=n^2))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWN83SNPI0bYtLczUqbHXzdPJ0QMxKCDM9OUWjQqdS09bWUE2tIs5IuzLOyMY2L85IUxOie19afpFGpq2BjoKhhY5CQVFmXomhRppGpqaCkoISTBHMKgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 61 bytes

```
f(n)=4\sum_{a=0}^n\sum_{b=1}^n0^{\gcd(a,b)-1}\{aa+bb<=nn,0\}
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xzmxeh7ob1)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wfu41krnsv)

I really feel like this can be golfed but I can't really think of anything at the moment. I also have this other version without the piecewise but it is 62 bytes:

```
f(n)=4∑_{a=0}^n∑_{b=1}^n0^{gcd(a,b)-1}sgn(sgn(nn-aa-bb)+1)
```

Comment: The Desmos function looks nice! $$f(n) = 4\sum_{a=0}^{n}\sum_{b=1}^{n}0^{\gcd\left(a,b\right)-1}\left\{aa+bb\le nn,0\right\}$$

Comment: @vengy Thanks! Though I strongly suspect there is a golfier formula than the one I came up with; I just can't seem to think of any golfs at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
(Ÿn¬sãʒ¿}€O@O
```

Straight-forward modification (adding `ʒ¿}€`) of [my 05AB1E answer for the related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/270011/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9vc2FiaWX//yjFuG7CrHPDo8qSwr994oKsT0BP//81) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9vc2FiaWX/dnk/IiDihpIgIj95RP8oxbhuwqxzw6PKksK/feKCrE9AT/8s/1swLDEsMiwzLDQsNV0).

**Explanation:**

```python
(             # Negate the (implicit) input-integer
 Ÿ            # Push a list in the range [(implicit) input,-input]
  n           # Square each inner value
   ¬          # Push the first item (without popping the list), which is input²
    s         # Swap so the list is at the top again
     ã        # Cartesian power of 2 to get all possible pairs
      ʒ }     # Filter this list of pairs by:
       ¿      #  Where the Greatest Common Divisor (gcd) of the pair is 1
              #  (note: only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E)
         €O   # Sum all remaining inner pairs together
              # (note: the `€` is only for n=0, so [] remains [], instead of becoming 0)
           @  # Check for each whether the input² is >= this value
            O # Sum to get the amount of truthy values
              # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

[Try it online with step-by-step output lines.](https://tio.run/##VZA9TgMxEIV7TjHaaiMtBQUNUgApkSIaFokSUThhdm3FsY1/WKWg4QhcgTZVCkSHtIiGY3CRZWwHIgrLkt9738yzdmwucBiKC2WCP4GiGvevZwfFJbbMI3iOIH6VMktX2gBTd2CC48BACufJk6yWqRbhJiWqw3TdxuTnW45e3wdmEZAtODwwGTCKKmsz9InRCBuBHldQJkK/HUEnPNfBg9HGCNUmYxwc8/1mB@@YqdJmLaGYlOR2TswlgmEEBd38y7mPlxyslVzDEtEkOXs7jjbVFxZmkykgbS4dHMXg13P//ribGVa5jVAKbcpGx/fTps6GCcfFEhpts42wxLT7f@23IBycjumF7r8/Od/jvU59YoKtdFA@9bDB83X2Oyg7LuIOVDFYOp7Ao4ipq2E4/gE)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 49 bytes

```r
\(n)sum(sapply(1:n^2,\(a)4*sum(!((1:a)^2+1)%%a)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY1LCsJADIb3nmJcFBI7QpNJx1HwJqUwCIOCltLHwrO4qYKH8jam-Nh8_4P85HbvpkfaP8chrcOLKmiwHy_Qx7Y9X4F2Tc22goiymuslaBWx5pwwyyIifofH_4CCTbhou1MzwAHEmmANeWscWyPqN6ph7rhQlJpoq2DWU_YKRxpdUCdSzBtFKRo9-d-_afroGw)

Uses the same OEIS chain [A000089](https://oeis.org/A000089) → [A304651](https://oeis.org/A304651) → [A175341](https://oeis.org/A175341) as in [@Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269991/55372).

Comment: Thanks for the OEIS chain!

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua 0.9.0](https://www.uiua.org/), 21 bytes <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>

```
×4/+≥⌵▽◰∩♭⊞⊃÷ℂ↘1.⇡+1.
```

[Try on Uiua Pad!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_9_0__w5c0LyviiaXijLXilr3il7DiiKnima3iip7iioPDt-KEguKGmDEu4oehKzEuIDUK) Takes \$r\$ as input and outputs the number of points

```
×4/+≥⌵▽◰∩♭⊞⊃÷ℂ↘1.⇡+1.­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
                 ⇡+1.  # ‎⁡push 0, 1, ... , r
              ↘1.      # ‎⁢push 1, 2, ... , r
          ⊞            # ‎⁣make tables of each possible pair (a,b)...
           ⊃÷ℂ         # ‎⁤with b/a and b+a*i
        ∩♭             # ‎⁢⁡flatten both tables into lists
       ◰               # ‎⁢⁢mask of unique quotients
      ▽                # ‎⁢⁣apply mask to list of complex numbers
     ⌵                 # ‎⁢⁤magnitudes
    ≥                  # ‎⁣⁡test less than or equal to r
  /+                   # ‎⁣⁢sum the number of such points
×4                     # ‎⁣⁣multiply by 4
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 96 bytes

```
.+
*_,$&*_,$&*
Lw`_+,_+,_*(?=_)
Am`^(__+)\1*,_+,\1*$
_+
$.&*$&
Cm`^(_+),\1(_*)(_*),\2$
.+
$.(4**
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9Pm0srXkdFDUJw@ZQnxGvrgJCWhr1tvCaXY25CnEZ8vLZmjKEWSBxIqXDFa3Op6KlpqahxOYOltTWB4hrxWpogrBNjpMKlB1KhYaKl9f@/AZchlxGXMZcJlykA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
*_,$&*_,$&*
```

Create a list `[r, r, r]` (in unary).

```
Lw`_+,_+,_*(?=_)
```

Create `r²` lists `[x=r..1, r, y=0..r-1]`.

```
Am`^(__+)\1*,_+,\1*$
```

Keep only the lists where `x` and `y` are coprime. (This particular implementation of the test assumes `x` is positive.)

```
_+
$.&*$&
```

Square `x`, `r` and `y`.

```
Cm`^(_+),\1(_*)(_*),\2$
```

Count (in decimal) the number of lists where `x²+y²<=r²`.

```
.+
$.(4**
```

Multiply by `4`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 19 bytes

```
Ｉ×⁴ΣＥ⊕ＸＮ²№Ｅι﹪⊕Ｘλ²ι⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEIyQzN7VYw0RHIbg0V8M3sUDDMy@5KDU3Na8kNUUjIL88tQgoUlBa4leamwRka@ooGGkCCef8UqAJIPWZOgq@@SmlOflYdOZAVWcCsYEmGFj//2/5X7csBwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Uses the formulae from OEIS, `A175341(n)=A304651(n²)=4ΣA000089(n²)`.

```
       Ｎ            Input `n` as an integer
      Ｘ             Raised to power
        ²           Literal integer `2`
     ⊕              Incremented
    Ｅ               Map over implicit range
         №          Count of
                  ⁰ Literal integer `0` in
           ι        Current value
          Ｅ         Map over implicit range
               λ    Inner value
              Ｘ     Raised to power
                ²   Literal integer `2`
             ⊕      Incremented
            ﹪       Modulo
                 ι  Current value
   Σ                Take the sum
 ×                  Times
  ⁴                 Literal integer `4`
Ｉ                   Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```

Note that the newer version of Charcoal on ATO allows you to vectorise the inner loop making it slightly more efficient, although the byte count is the same:

```
Ｉ×⁴ΣＥ⊕ＸＮ²№﹪⊕Ｘ…⁰ι²ι⁰
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6FjcrAooy80o0nBOLSzRCMnNTizVMdBSCS3M1fBMLNDzzkotSc1PzSlJTNALyy1OLgCIFpSV-pblJQLamjoKRJpBwzi8FmuCbn1Kak49FS1BiXnqqhoGOQiZMA4hhsKQ4KbkY6orl0Uq6ZTlKsQsNIHwA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 37 chars

```
+/{(1=∨/⍵)∧0≥-/2⌽∊2*⍨r⍵}¨,∘.,⍨r..-r←⎕
```

test:

```
  +/{(1=∨/⍵)∧0≥-/2⌽∊2*⍨r⍵}¨,∘.,⍨r..-r←⎕
⎕:
  10
192
  +/{(1=∨/⍵)∧0≥-/2⌽∊2*⍨r⍵}¨,∘.,⍨r..-r←⎕
⎕:
  0
0
  +/{(1=∨/⍵)∧0≥-/2⌽∊2*⍨r⍵}¨,∘.,⍨r..-r←⎕
⎕:
  5
48
```